# About Form method's

Tags: php, forms, post, methods, get

As a junior trying to make form like google form and I want to collect data using GET/POST form methods in my project.  I tried some code in books but I get clear page or no output from the form.  Also, I want only to see this data not to appear to clients, what is the best way to do that?

**Simple code I used**:

```html
/* PHP --- index.php*/


<form action="collect.php" method="POST"> 
    <input type="text" name="name" id="inputName">
    <br><br>
    <input type="password" name="name" id="inputNumber">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

**Used this codes**

```
/*collect.php*/


<?php

$id = '';
$name ='';

if(isset($_GET['id']))
  $id = $_GET['id'];

if(isset($_GET['name']))
  $name =$_GET['name']; "<br>";

    echo $id . '-' . $name;

foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
    
    echo $key . '=' .$value . '<br>';
}

?>

<?php

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    
    echo $key . ': ' . $value . '<br>';
    
}
?>
```

Comment: You can remove the second PHP opening tag `<?php` and keep the one at the beginning of the file. You can also omit the closing tag. Can you check from your network tab in your browser if the request is successfull?

Comment: You also need to give unique names to your form field for username and password. Having the same name will result in getting the last value of the form for that field. However, I cannot reproduce the issue as I am getting the form values correctly.

Comment: Yup thanks , i was commented first code ,  but still didnt get my question

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your form action to this action="./collect.php"

Comment: Yup its success thanks so much <3